# R regex extract rating out of 10 from string

Tags: regex, r

I have some text strings that I would like to extract certain bits of information from. In particular I would like to extract the rating out of 10 from.

I would like help in constructing a function`func_to_extract_rating` that does the following...

```
text_string_vec <- c('blah$2.94 blah blah 3/10 blah blah.',
                     'foo foo 8/10.',
                     '10/10 bar bar21/09/2010 bar bar',
                     'jdsfs1/10djflks5/10.')

func_to_extract_rating <- function(){}

output <- lapply(text_string_vec,func_to_extract_rating)
output
[[1]]
[1]  3 10

[[2]]
[1]  8 10

[[3]]
[1] 10 10

[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1]  1 10

[[4]][[2]]
[1]  5 10
```

Comment: `y <- regmatches(text_string_vec, gregexpr('\\d+/10', text_string_vec)); rapply(y, strsplit, split = '/', how = 'list')`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this maybe:

```
library(stringr)

result = str_extract_all(text_string_vec, "[0-9]{1,2}/10")
result = lapply(result, function(x) gsub("/"," ", x))

[[1]]
[1] "3 10"

[[2]]
[1] "8 10"

[[3]]
[1] "10 10"

[[4]]
[1] "1 10" "5 10"
```

But since it's always out of 10, if you just want the numeric rating, you can do:

```
result = str_extract_all(text_string_vec, "[0-9]{1,2}/10")
result = lapply(result, function(x) as.numeric(gsub("/10","", x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` option

```
lapply(strsplit(str1, "([0-9]{1,2}\\/10)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.", perl = TRUE),
         function(x) {
         lst <- lapply(strsplit(x[nzchar(x)], "/"), as.numeric)
         if(length(lst)==1) unlist(lst) else lst})
#[[1]]
#[1]  3 10

#[[2]]
#[1]  8 10

#[[3]]
#[1] 10 10

#[[4]]
#[[4]][[1]]
#[1]  1 10

#[[4]][[2]]
#[1]  5 10
```